# Float an element over other elements and push some, but not all, elements down

Tags: html, css

Please see this [This Image](http://www1.picturepush.com/photo/a/7590049/img/Anonymous/css-problem.jpg) for a picture of the problem.

I have a div that displays a list under a text field. It is a fake Combo-box, using a text element and JavaScript. The list that appears when someone types *should* cover the other form elements, but should also make the wrapper div bigger so it doesn't get cut off. I have only been able to do one or the other.

Here's The relevant HTML

```
<td id="EditorMainColumn">
   <div id="EditorPanesWrapper">
      <div style="display: block;"><!-- a Jquery Tools Tab, also the problem div -->
           <div class="EditorFormFieldWrapper">
              <label>My Field</label>
              <input class="EditorInput" name="name">
           </div>
           <br class="ClearBoth"><!-- I don't know if this helps or not -->
           <div class="ComboBoxListWrapper">
              <div class="ComboBoxList">
                  <!-- <a> elements are inserted dynamically here --> 
                 <br class="ClearBoth"><!-- I don't know if this helps or not -->
              </div>
           </div>
           <div><!-- Cover me! -->
              You can't see this when the combo box is open...
           </div>
      </div><!-- END display:block div -->
   </div><!-- END EditorPanesWrapper -->
</td>
```

**CSS**:

```
#EditorMainColumn {
   overflow:hidden!important;
   background:#f9f9f4;
   border-top:1px solid black;
   padding:20px;
   color:#432c01;
}

#EditorPanesWrapper {
   width:auto;
   margin-right:20px;
   overflow:auto;
}

.ComboBoxListWrapper{
position:relative;
top:-10px;
}

.ComboBoxList{
 border: 1px solid red;
 width:288px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
 margin-left:180px;
}

.ComboBoxList a {
   display:block;
   border: 1px solid #DDD7C6;
   border-top:0px;
   float: left;      
   padding: 8px;
   padding-left:0px;
   top:-11px;
   color: #432C01;
   width:279px;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 10px;
   background:white;
}
```

How do I get the div to expand for the combo-box's height while still keeping the options list over/above the other form elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i notice using this

EditorPanesWrapper

inside the TD make the size fix,

Try to give an specific width and height in % if you want it to adjust to the content of your page.

Another question why do you need to put it into a table ? you can just use div

Comment: The layout I'm using can only be done with a table, and EditorPanesWrapper must be dynamically sized for that layout to work. I need a solution that does not involve changing the layout of the screen.

Comment: #EditorPanesWrapper- removing `width:auto` and `overflow:auto` then adding `width:100%` and `height:100%` seems to have solved the problem. There was some reason we had the previous settings though, so I'm going to try this for a while and see if any layout bugs appear.